# Detecting array type do not works

Tags: c++, templates

```
template<typename T> 
class CompoundT {           // primary template 
  public: 
    enum { IsPtrT = 0, IsRefT = 0, IsArrayT = 0, 
           IsFuncT = 0, IsPtrMemT = 0 }; 
    typedef T BaseT; 
    typedef T BottomT; 
    typedef CompoundT<void> ClassT; 
};

template<typename T, size_t N> 
class CompoundT <T[N]> {    // partial specialization for arrays 
  public: 
    enum { IsPtrT = 0, IsRefT = 0, IsArrayT = 1, 
           IsFuncT = 0, IsPtrMemT = 0 }; 
    typedef T BaseT; 
    typedef typename CompoundT<T>::BottomT BottomT; 
    typedef CompoundT<void> ClassT; 
};
```

and in main:

```
template<class T>
bool isArray(T a)
{
    return CompoundT<T>::IsArrayT;
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
    {
        int a[10];
        cout << isArray(a);
        return 0;
}
```

Why this doesn't work? This example is from "Templates the complete guide" ch.19.2.

Comment: Won't I need `size_t N` in the first template too so that the second one is considered as a partial specialization of the first?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because isArray must take reference, otherwise if you take an array by value it's the same as if you take a pointer :)

```
template <class T>
bool isArray(const T& ) {...}
```

because

```
void f(int a[10]);
```

and

```
void f(int* a);
```

are equivalent declarations.

Comment: @There: No, as a matter of fact, I just got home 5 min ago. Was my answer helpful?

Comment: yes, thank you. Can't accept though. Have to wait 15 minutes.

Comment: @There The same is with functions, if you take a function by value, it's the same as if you took a pointer to function. The same is with templates. If a templated function takes T by value and you pass a function then T is a pointer to function. if you take T by reference, T will be function